# I followed the instructions and my XML and XSL files are not working

Tags: xml, validation, xslt

1.Go to the hbemployees.xsl file in your editor. Directly after the opening stylesheet element, create the departments key, matching the employee element and using the department element for the key index. The purpose of this key will be to group the employees by department.

2. Directly after the h1 Employee Report heading, insert a for-each element that that uses Muenchian grouping to select each unique department by using the location path: “//employee[generate-id()=generate-id(key(‘departments’, department)[1])]”
   then sort the results by department.
3. Each time through the for-each loop, write the following HTML code to the result document:

   ```
   <table class="employeeList"> <caption>department</caption> <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Position</th>
   <th>Salary</th>
   <th>Phone</th>
   <th>Gender</th>
   <th>Marital Status</th>
   <th>Work Status</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

where department is the value of the department element.

4. Within the tbody element of the HTML code you just wrote, apply a template using the
   departments key with the current value of the department element in order to display information on each employee within the currently displayed department. Sort the applied template by descending order of the salary element.
5. Directly after the root template, insert a new template matching the employee element. The purpose of this template will be to write a table row containing information on a selected employee. Have the template write the following HTML code to the result document:

   ```
   <tr>
   <td>name</td> 
   <td>position</td> 
   <td>salary</td> 
   <td>phone</td>
   <td>gender</td>
   <td>marital status</td>
   <td>working status</td>
   </tr>
   ```

   where name, position, salary, phone, gender, marital status, and working status are the values of the name, position, salary, phone, gender, martialStatus, and workingStatus elements. Format salary so that it is displayed as currency.

I am not sure why my files are not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML, 3rd Edition
   Tutorial 7
   Case Problem 1

   Harris and Barnes Style Sheet

   Filename:         hbemployees.xsl
   Supporting Files: hbemployees.xml
-->


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:key name="departments" match="employee" use="department" />

   <xsl:variable name="hbemployessDoc" select="document('hbemployess.xml')" />

   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />


   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Employee Report</title>
            <link href="hbstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">
               <header>
                  <img src="hblogo.png" alt="Harris and Barnes" />
               </header>

               <h1>Employee Report</h1>
               <xsl:for-each
                       select="//employee[generate-id()=generate-id(key('departments', department)[1])]">
               <xsl:sort select="department" />

                  <table class="employeeList">
                     <caption><xsl:value-of select="department"/></caption>
                     <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Marital Status</th>
                        <th>Work Status</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('departments', department)">
                        <xsl:sort select="salary" order="descending" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>

               </xsl:for-each>

             </div>
         </body>

      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="employee">
      <tr>

            <td>  <xsl:value-of select="name" /> </td>
         <td> <xsl:value-of select="position" /> </td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(salary,'$#,##0')"/></td>
         <td> <xsl:value-of select="phone" /> </td>
         <td> <xsl:value-of select="gender" /></td>
         <td> <xsl:value-of select="maritalStatus" /></td>
         <td> <xsl:value-of select="workingStatus" /></td>
   </tr>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: Following is a sample of the xml that belongs with this Tutorial

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hbemployees.xsl" ?>

<employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <employee empID="4">
      <name>Heffner, Marian</name>
      <position>Chief Operating Officer</position>
      <phone>x10962</phone>
      <email>mheffner50@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>262000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="192">
      <name>Murff, Nicolle</name>
      <position>Mgr Software Client Supp</position>
      <phone>x32524</phone>
      <email>nmurff63@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>137000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="295">
      <name>Vecchio, Art</name>
      <position>Line Worker</position>
      <phone>x12125</phone>
      <email>avecchio55@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>83000</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Part Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="294">
      <name>Lewis, Richard</name>
      <position>Met Read/Coll</position>
      <phone>x22131</phone>
      <email>rlewis19@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Production</department>
      <salary>74500</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="193">
      <name>Fleming, Angela</name>
      <position>Inventory Ck</position>
      <phone>x31751</phone>
      <email>afleming30@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>99000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples of the XML input, the XSLT you have, the output you want and the error or wrong output you get. How do you run the XSLT, what happens exactly if it is not working?

Comment: The line `<xsl:variable name="hbemployessDoc" select="document('hbemployess.xml')" />` declares a variable not being used, if I take that out then https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9v shows some HTML result. So how do you run the XSLT, which output do you get? Or is it just any XSLT not working because you perhaps use Chrome and try to load files from the local file system?